# Excel VBA ComboBox DropButtonClick() event fires twice

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have an elaborate dashboard that makes use of several userforms and many controls in each userform. The specific question I have deals with the `ComboBox_DropButtonClick()` event which appears to be firing twice. The combobox has two events currently, the `DropButtonClick()`event - where I populate the combo box list via array, and a `ComboBox_Change()` event. What I'm finding and trying to prevent is that when I click the dropbutton, the `DropButtonClick()` event fires as expected. When the list appears on the userform, I make a selection. After I've clicked on one of the items, the `ComboBox_Change()` event fires - also as expected. However, when the `ComboBox_Change()` event finishes, the `ComboBox_DropButtonClick()` event fires an additional time, presumably when it closes? I'd prefer the second `DropButtonClick()` not fire because it runs that code an additional time.

Rather than provide the elaborate dashboard code and also to confirm my findings, I created a second, brand new workbook to demonstrate the issue. I created a single user form, with a single combobox. I created the same two events: `DropButtonClick()` and `Change()`. I then wrote a similar snippet of code to populate the combobox list from an array, and then print the combobox value to an arbitrary cell on a blank worksheet. I used a breakpoint in the `DropButtonClick()` event to help step through the sequence and confirm the events are firing as I've described above.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Thisworkbook.worksheets(1).Range("A5") = Me.ComboBox1.Value

end sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()  
dim arr as variant  
dim I as integer  

for I = 0 to 5  
    if IsEmpty(arr) then  
        redim arr(0)  
    else  
        redim preserve arr(ubound(arr)+1)  
    end if  
    arr(ubound(arr)) = "A" & I  
next I  

Me.ComboBox1.List = arr  

end sub
```

I would expect the `DropButtonClick()` event to fire, which will show me the array of elements to choose from. Then, I make a selection from the option, which should fire the `Change()` event and print to the worksheet. Check. that all happens. then for some reason, after that has taken place, the `DropButtonClick()` event fires one more time before all of the execution completes. Trying to understand why the `DropButtonClick()` event happens twice, and how I might avoid the second event without having to embed a public Boolean variable that exits immediately if `true` (for example)

Comment: From the [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dropbuttonclick-event) for the `DropButtonClick` event - "Occurs whenever the drop-down list appears or disappears"

Comment: It's common practice to have a `sub` that initializes the `userform` and its elements and is triggered by the click of a button which `loads` and `shows` the `userform`. I suggest you populate your combobox in that `sub` and not by using the `DropButtonClick` event.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The reason I have many combo boxes populate upon drop down click is because I use them in a down select process so that each subsequent combo box doesn't have 100% of the available options, but rather reflects a filtered subset reflective of a previous selection the user made. If, for example, the first combobox is STATE, and the user selects California before moving to the next combobox, I want the CITY combo box to recognize the state and only provide the user a list of applicable cities rather than all the cities.